# ReadItLater-type app that saves web articles but also allows highlighting?

Tags: pdf, evernote, instapaper, highlights, pocket

I use [Pocket](http://getpocket.com) and I love it as a way of saving articles to read them later, and how it allows me to browse, search, and read them easily.

However, when I read articles, I like to create highlights (in yellow) and add annotations. Pocket doesn't offer highlighting.

There's a great OSX app for PDFs, [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/), that highlights and annotates perfectly when I'm reading a PDF. But it would be so much better to not have to convert a web page to PDF in order to highlight and annotate it.

I would like to be able to create my own library of archived web articles (like Pocket allows me to do) that I can tag, search, and mark up.

Is there a "read it later" type app that will allow me to create my own library of archived web articles that I can then highlight and annotate?

Answer (score 1):

A recent update of [Instapaper](https://www.instapaper.com/iphone) (May 8, 2014) allows highlighting. Any highlights you create are saved into your saved version of the article and are visible online as well.

Comment: Instapaper doesn't even have an OSX client does it?

Comment: That's true - there are no clients for OSX, Windows or Linux. However, I use the online version of Instapaper.com to save and read articles too, and the online version supports highlighting as well (see http://blog.instapaper.com/post/85125160146).

Comment: Yes, there is a 3rd party macOS client: [ReadKit](http://readkitapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. It's called dotdotdot and it's not as polished as Instapaper, Pocket or Readability but shows promise. Visit their site at [dotdotdot.me](http://dotdotdot.me)